# How can I convert a array.map().toList to a generic type?

Tags: dart

I have below code in `dart`:

```
List<Post> posts = postsData.map((post) =>
        Post(
            id: post['id'],
            message: post['message']
      ).toList();
```

It runs `map` on an array and return an array with the type `Post`. But I got this error `_TypeError (type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<Post>')` when executing the above code.
I can fix it by adding `List<Post>.from` like below:

```
List<Post> posts = List<Post>.from(postsData.map((post) =>
        Post(
            id: post['id'],
            message: post['message']
      ).toList());
```

I wonder is it the correct way to do that? Why doesn't `toList` work for the generic type `Post`? Why is it saying `List<dynamic>` even I return `Post` inside the `map` loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its weird that I am not getting any `_TypeError`.

You can try specify generic type on `.map<Post>`

```
List<Post> posts = postsData.map<Post>((post) =>
        Post(
            id: post['id'],
            message: post['message']
      )).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
List<Post> posts = postsData.map((post) =>
    Post(
        id: post['id'],
        message: post['message']
  ).whereType<Post>().toList();
```